# height inherit not working with absolute position

Tags: html, css, absolute

I have an absolute element that is the background. I can't set it as the div's background because it is animated and it requires 2 css classes. I simplified it to let you understand the problem.

I would like to set the height of this absolute element same of its parent, which, containing all the other elements, reaches the bottom of the page. So this absolute element that I use as background should cover all the background page, but inherit is not working.

I tried also `height:100%` but it didn't work. It works only if I set manually the height, but doing like this is not responsive.

```css
.stars {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:inherit;
  height:inherit;
  display:block;
}

.stars {
  background:#000 url(http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/360/images/stars.png) repeat top center;
  z-index:0;
}
        
.main-content {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.home-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 5;
}

.genericDiv1, .genericDiv2, .genericDiv3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.genericDiv1 {
  background-color:#f00;
}

.genericDiv2 {
  background-color:#00ff76;
}

.genericDiv3 {
  background-color:#2900ff;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="main-content">
      <div class="stars"></div>
      <div class="home-container">
         <div class="genericDiv1"></div>
         <div class="genericDiv2"></div>
         <div class="genericDiv3"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

I want to specify that if I set the `.main-content` class with a specific height it works. But as I said before, in this way it is not responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, you need to **correctly position the `.stars` div absolutely by positioning its parent div `.main-content` relatively**. (Absolutely positioned elements need their parents to be relatively positioned otherwise they will be positioned absolutely to the body element). Then set the height of `.main-content` to `100vh` (not 100%, because its parent `body` has no specified height) to take up the full height of the viewport (i.e screen).

1. **Position the `.main-content` div relatively and height to 100vh**. Now the `.stars` div can inherit this full height. Like so:

   ```
   .main-content {
       ...
       position: relative;  
       height: 100vh;
       ...
    }
   ```

   Alternatively, set the height of the body element to `100vh` first, then set the height of the `.main-content` div to `100%` to inherit the full height of the viewport.

   ```
   body {
       height: 100vh;
   } 

   .main-content {
       ...
       position: relative;  
       height: 100%;
       ...
    }
   ```
2. **Additionally, remove browser default paddings and margins and prevent overshooting widths and heights of elements** on your page by setting the `padding` and `margin` properties of all elements to `0` and setting `box-sizing: border-box` property for all of them. Place this at the top of your CSS (This is good CSS practice).

   ```
   * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
       padding: 0;
       margin: 0;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your css:
‌‌‌
-Remove`height : 100%`from `.main-content`and add`height:100vh`
‌‌‌‌‌

-add a `position:relative` to `.main-content`

Tell me what is going on.